# css selector syntax: "element1 element2" VS "element1 > element2"

Tags: css, css-selectors

what is the difference between selector strategy 1 and 2? It seems the same to me

1. div p   (Selects all `<p`> elements inside `<div`> elements)
2. div > p     (Selects all `<p`> elements where the parent is a `<div`> element)

Comment: a quick search on google and you get that easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selector #1 (`div p`) selects all paragraphs that are descendants of a div. The `p` elements could be deeply nested in the div structure, and they will be selected.

Selector #2 (`div > p`) selects only paragraphs that are the children (i.e., immediate descendants) of a div.

The first is known as a *descendant combinator selector*.

The second is a *child combinator selector*.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 2):

Using `>` selects only the elements which is a direct child, in below case only `span` which is a direct child of a `div`

```css
div span {
  color: red
}
div > span {
  color: lime
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>Span</span>
  <span>
    Span
    <span>Span</span>
    <span>Span</span>
  </span>
</div>
```